# Pandas - replace, float and sum of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, precision

I have an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a=[['1','221,51','413,56','636,07'],['13','213','131.86','357,86'],['49','239.83','-238.83','10']]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
repl_list = {',': '.'}
df.replace(repl_list, regex=True, inplace=True)


df[0] = df[0].astype(float)
df[1] = df[1].astype(float)
df[2] = df[2].astype(float)
df[3] = df[3].astype(float)

df['SUM'] = df.loc[df[0] >= 0, [0, 1, 2]].sum(axis=1)
df['SUM'] = df['SUM'].astype(float)
df['SUM'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['T/F'] = np.where((df['SUM'] >= df[3]), True, False)
a = df.loc[df['T/F'] == False]
print(df)
```

if `sum [3] == SUM` column, then it should be `True`, otherwise `False`

why with this code the result is:

```
      0       1       2       3     SUM    T/F
0   1.0  221.51  413.56  636.07  636.07  False
1  13.0  213.00  131.86  357.86  357.86   True
2  49.0  239.83 -238.83   10.00   50.00   True
```

Why in 2 shows true even though it should be false?
The same problem in the first row - should be true.

How does this float converter work?
When I add to `a[]` values `['49','239.83','-288.83','10']` output looks like:

```
      0       1       2       3           SUM    T/F
0   1.0  221.51  413.56  636.07  6.360700e+02  False
1  13.0  213.00  131.86  357.86  3.578600e+02   True
2  49.0  239.83 -238.83   10.00  5.000000e+01   True
3  49.0  239.83 -288.83   10.00  5.684342e-14  False
```

Why does it look like this? Where is mistake and what does this float sum look like? Please explain how it works and why there is an error.

True should be only if column `'3'` is equal to `SUM` - I don't understand why it doesn't work - what about the first row? It totally doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

Because float precision if compare equal values is possible some values not matched.

Here is possible use [`numpy.isclose.html`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html?highlight=isclose#numpy.isclose) for compare equality:

```
df['T/F'] = np.isclose(df['SUM'], df[3])
print(df)
      0       1       2       3     SUM    T/F
0   1.0  221.51  413.56  636.07  636.07   True
1  13.0  213.00  131.86  357.86  357.86   True
2  49.0  239.83 -238.83   10.00   50.00  False
```

Then add condition for compare higher values and chain by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df['T/F'] = np.isclose(df['SUM'], df[3]) | (df['SUM'] > df[3])
print(df)
      0       1       2       3     SUM   T/F
0   1.0  221.51  413.56  636.07  636.07  True
1  13.0  213.00  131.86  357.86  357.86  True
2  49.0  239.83 -238.83   10.00   50.00  True
```

Comment: Can these larger numbers be converted to normal float values? Somehow limit the number of decimals when adding up, or limiting when displaying? Where is the problem? Is it about float accuracy? Can it be changed somehow?

Regarding the solution - Well, you are right, it is definitely a better solution and it makes sense. And out of curiosity - it can be solved using `np.where`?

Comment: @DeepSea - `np.where` is here reduntant, because same output, but is possible use `np.where(np.isclose(df['SUM'], df[3]) | (df['SUM'] > df[3]), True, False)`

Answer (score 1):

That is due the floating point precision of both of the values in the columns `3` and `SUM`.

```
df[3][0]
# 636.07
df['SUM'][0]
# 636.0699999999999
```

To count this use [`np.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) and set precision.

```
df['T/F']=np.round(df['SUM'],2)>=np.round(df[3],2)
print(df)

      0       1       2       3     SUM   T/F
0   1.0  221.51  413.56  636.07  636.07  True
1  13.0  213.00  131.86  357.86  357.86  True
2  49.0  239.83 -238.83   10.00   50.00  True
```